# exportSVG asString doesn't work in paper.js

Tags: paperjs

Using [paper.js](http://paperjs.org), `project.exportSVG({asString: true})` returns an SVGSVGElement instead of a string. Did I write this code wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try again with the latest nightly build. This should work now in all situations.